# Format Decimal so it shows 123,456.78 but to not show 00.00 when 0

Tags: c#

I have Decimal values that have `123456.78` and I want to format it to be `123,456.78`

for this I'm doing `@$"{value:0,0.00}"`  but I don't know if it's the best approach, but at first glance is that when the decimal has 0, the value shown is 00.00 which looks weird.
Is there a suggestion to do it better than with the interpolation.
I'm storing monetary amounts, but different currencies so using currency wouldn't be the best (as it comes from a float value from database -I know, bad- and a separate field specifies the currency code for it).

so, to put it short, what to do best to express decimal with `123,456.78` format and to show `0.00` for 0 values.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see the documentation on [Custom numeric format strings - The ";" section separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator) which allows you to specify formats for positive, negative and zero values.

Comment: ${value:N} works just fine for you case from what it seems

Comment: You could also use this: @$"{value:#,0.00}"

Comment: Almost but N is culture dependent but he uses currently something culture ignorant.

Comment: You could also just replace the leading `0` in your format string for a `#` i.e. $"{value:#,0.00}" will result in "0.00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#` to add placeholders that are not used if the digit is a leading zero:

```
foreach (var value in new [] {123456.78 , 0})
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value:#,0.00}");
}
```

output:

```
123,456.78
0.00
```